# CORS issue in Node.js Express application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm currently working on a Node.js Express backend with a React frontend, and I'm encountering CORS-related issues when attempting to make requests from my React app to the Express API.

Despite including the CORS middleware in my Express server, I'm still facing CORS issues. Are there additional configurations or steps I should take to ensure proper handling of CORS in this setup?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue in backend, you can follow these steps:
Install CORS in your backend using this command :

```
npm install cors
```

Once it installed, import the CORS module into your main server file.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://yourfrontenddomain.com', // replace it with the actual domain of your frontend application 
  credentials: true
}));
```

or

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: '*', // Allow requests from any frontend domain
  credentials: true
}));
```